# How to embed SAP BO objects into HTML containers?

Tags: html, business-objects

Is it possible to embed a SAP BO object into a HTML container? For instance, embed a dashboard into my page instead of opening a new tab redirecting to the BO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OpenDocument, and put that in an [iframe](http://www.w3ctutorial.com/html5-tags/tag-iframe) in your HTML page, you should be able to embed the BusinessObjects content into your web page, provided the object type is supported by OpenDocument (e.g. WebI, Dashboards, …).

One thing to keep in mind is that the user will still need to authenticate to the BusinessObjects platform. Setting up SSO results in automatic authentication, thus not prompting your end-user. If SSO is not possible, there are ways to authenticate the user without prompting (e.g. setting up trusted authentication, using the SDK to retrieve a logon token in the background, etc).

OpenDocument manuals are available [here](http://help.sap.com/bobip?current=bobi&show_children=false). Just make sure to select the correct manual corresponding to your version of BusinessObjects, as the features tend to differ between versions.